# Prove the complex polynomial $P(z,\bar{z})$ is zero if and only if all the coefficient is zero.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $F(z,\bar{z}) = \sum_i^n a_i z^i + \sum_j^m b_j \bar{z}^j$ which $a_i,b_i \in \mathbb{C}$ .

Prove if $F(z,\bar{z}) = 0$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$,then $a_i,b_j = 0$.

I can prove this by taking derivative on $z$ and $\bar{z}$(it's possible since Frechet differentiable).Is there some other alternative proof?

Comment: Can't you prove that the term of highest degree dominates (for $|z|$ sufficiently large) and then observe that that term is unbounded? Or, take the (square of the) modulus, yielding a real polynomial in two variables, and apply a theorem about real polynomials?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson thanks,for the second solution do you mean convert it to $|F(z,\bar{z})|^2 = 0 = G(u,v)$ where $u + i v = z$？The coefficient then seems hard to manage?

Comment: $F(z,\overline z)=p(u,v)+iq(u,v)$ so $|F(z,\overline z)|^2=(p(u,v))^2+(q(u,v))^2$ where $p,q$ are real polynomials. Again, there should be a highest, dominating term.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson The coefficient for $|F(z,\overline z)|^2=(p(u,v))^2+(q(u,v))^2$ is zero may not implies $a_i,b_j = 0$?

Comment: I'm sure it does, but if that's too hard to prove, maybe my first suggestion is better.

Comment: Regarding your title, this is not ordinarily considered a complex polynomial.

Comment: I wonder how you would prove this for more general polynomials in two variables: $P(z, \bar z) = \sum_{i,j} a_{i,j} z^i \bar z^j$, which is what I thought first when reading the title...

Comment: @Daniel Schepler since $P(z,\bar{z}) = 0$ as zero polynomial is a harmonic polynomial,hence it must has the form $F(z,\bar{z}) = \sum_i^n a_i z^i + \sum_j^m b_j \bar{z}^j$ ?

Comment: @DanielSchepler See the update of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W.lo.g. we may assume that $n \ge m$. Hence we may even assume $n = m$ (otherwise fill with coefficients $b_{m+1} = 0,\ldots, b_n = 0$). Thus for all $z$
$$F(z) = \sum_{j=0}^n (a_j z^j + b_j \bar{z}^j)= 0 .$$
Note that I suppressed $\bar z$ from $F(z, \bar z)$ because $\bar z$ is uniquely determined by $z$.

Write $z = e^{i\theta}x$ with $\theta, x \in \mathbb R$. Then
$$F(z) = \sum_{j=0}^n (e^{i\theta j}a_j + e^{-i\theta j}b_j) x^j= 0 .$$
Separating real and imaginary part of $F(z)$ yields two real ploynomials in the variable $x$ which are both $0$. This shows $\Re(e^{i\theta j}a_j + e^{-i\theta j}b_j) = 0$ and $\Im(e^{i\theta j}a_j + e^{-i\theta j}b_j) = 0$ for all $j$ and all $\theta$, hence
$$e^{i\theta j}a_j + e^{-i\theta j}b_j  = 0 .$$
Taking $\theta = 0$ we get
$$a_j + b_j = 0. \tag{1}$$
For $j > 0$ we take $\theta = \pi/2j$ and get
$$ia_j  - ib_j = 0, \text{ i.e. } a_j = b_j. \tag{2}$$
$(1)$ and $(2)$ show that $a_j =  b_j = 0$ for $j > 0$. Thus
$$F(z) = a_0 + b_0 = 0 .$$

For $j = 0$ we **cannot** conclude that $a_0 = b_0 = 0$. In fact, we may take any $a_0 \in \mathbb C$ and $b_0 = -a_0$.

**Update:**

Daniel Schepler suggests in a comment to consider the more general
$$P(z)  = \sum_{j,k} a_{jk}z^j \bar z^k .$$
This has an additional benefit: The constant term is $a_{00}$ and does not split as $a_0 + b_0$.

With $z = e^{i\theta}x$ we get
$$P(z) =  \sum_{j,k} e^{i\theta (j - k)}a_{jk}x^{j+k}$$
and conclude that for all $n$ and $\theta$
$$\sum_{j+k=n} e^{i\theta (j - k)}a_{jk} = \sum_{j=0}^n e^{i\theta (2j - n)}a_{j(n-j)} = 0 .$$
Via multiplying with $e^{i\theta n}$ we see that this is equivalent to
$$\sum_{j=0}^n e^{i\theta 2j}a_{j(n-j)} = \sum_{j=0}^n (e^{2i\theta})^ja_{j(n-j)} = 0 .$$
That is, for each $\theta$ we have a linear equation for the $n+1$ variables $a_{0n},\ldots,a_{n0}$.

Let $\theta_l = \frac{\pi l}{2(n+1)}$ for $l = 0,\ldots,n$. These are $n+1$ distinct points and we get a system of $n+1$ linear equations for the $a_{0n},\ldots,a_{n0}$. The matrix of this system is the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) $V = V(\theta_0,\ldots,\theta_n)$ whose determinant is $\prod_{0\le r < s \le n} (\theta_s - \theta_r)$. Thus $\det V \ne 0$ which implies that $a_{0n} = \ldots = a_{n0} = 0$.

Comment: thanks, nice proof.